# I dont understand y---3 statement

Tags: c, statements

Why `y---3` statement behave like `y = 3` ? Can someone explain?

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){

   int x=-2, y=4, z;
   y---3;
   printf("%d",y);
}
```

Comment: Change the initial value of `y` and see what happens.

Comment: somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-operator-in-c

Answer (score 8):

C tries to read its tokens greedily, i.e. it tries to read and match as long sequences as it can. Therefore the `---` will be parsed as `-- -`, which means you have `y-- - 3`.

Since you don't store the result anywhere, the only relevant bit is `y--`, which decreases `y` from `4` to `3`.

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
y---3;
```

Parses as:

```
y-- - 3;
```

So this expression decrements `y`, takes the prior value of `y` and subtracts 3 from it.  The result of the expression (i.e. 1) is discarded because it is used as a statement by itself.

Answer (score 2):

`y---3;` is not the same as `y = 3`.

`y--3` is parsed as `(y--) - 3`, and the final result of the subtraction is discarded. So the only side effect of `y--` is retained, decrementing `1` from the earlier value of `y`, which was `4`.

For that matter, `y---n`, where `n` is any integer will produce the same result for the next print statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you compile this with warnings enabled, your compiler will tell you (amongst other warnings) something like:

```
test.c:6:7: warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]
    y---3;
    ~~~^~
```

In this case, the code, written more readably, is:

```
    y-- - 3;
```

which is equivalent to:

```
    y - 3;
    y -= 1;
```

The first of these statements is redundant, because you are computing a value and then discarding it.